# Q: the proof of Theorem 17.4 in Munkres's topology

Tags: general-topology

Theorem 17.4 Let $Y$ be a subspace of $X$, let $A$ be a subset of $Y$, let $\overline{A}$ denote the closure of $A$ in $X$. Then the closure of $A$ in $Y$ equals $\overline{A}\cap Y$.

In the proof, the author assert that "$\overline{A}\cap Y\space \supset\space A$", why?

Comment: Why cannot we use "contains" in place of $\supseteq$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$A\subset Y$ by assumption and $A\subset \overline{A}$ by definition implies the result.

Answer (score 1):

Because it is always true that $\;T\subset\overline T\;$ for any subspace $\;T\;$ of a topological space, since by definition

$$\overline T:=\bigcap_{T\subset C}\left\{C\;\text{ is closed}\right\}$$

and it is also given thay $\;A\subset Y\;$, so we have $\;A\subset \overline A\;$ and $\;A\subset Y\implies A\subset \overline A\cap Y\;$